# Get multiple values from LI choice

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following code which fetches the value of a LI chosen by the user.

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['target'])) {
$scrollx = $_POST['target']; } else {
            $scrollx = 0;   
                }
            echo $scrollx;

        ?>
```

This section gets the value in the hidden form field

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-left" role="menu">

<input type="hidden" name="target"  id="target" value="">
<li><a class="target" id="t1" name="target" rel='1' href="#">UK Tote</a></li>
<li><a class="target" id="t2" name="target" rel='2' href="#">Data Tote</a></li>
<li><a class="target" id="t3" name="target" rel='3' href="#">Tote Ireland</a></li>
<li><a class="target" id="t4" name="target" rel='4' href="#">PMU</a></li>
<li><a class="target" id="t5" name="target" rel='5' href="#">Fintoto</a></li>
<li><a class="target" id="t6" name="target" rel='6' href="#">ATG</a></li>
</ul>
```

This section is within my Form

```
<script type="application/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.target').click(function(){
$('#target').val($(this).attr('rel'));
$('#myform').submit();
});
});
</script>
```

The above is my jquery which pushed the chosen LI value into my hidden and then submits the page

My question is this:
If I want the LI to have more than one value ie rel2 as well as rel

```
<li><a class="target" id="t1" name="target" rel='1'  rel2='A'  href="#">UK Tote</a></li>
```

How can I adjust my code so that i can get this value as well when the page is submitted

Comment: Add another hidden input, and do the same for the rel2, set the value of the second hidden input etc.

Comment: OK that was easy thanks for the prompt - my adjusted code for anyone coming along later:

    <?php if (isset($_POST['target'])) {
    $scrollx = $_POST['target']; 
    $scroll2 = $_POST['target2']; 
    } else {
    $scrollx = 0;$scroll2 = 0; 
    }
    echo $scrollx;
    echo $scroll2;
    ?>

    <li><a class="target" id="t1" name="target" rel='1' rel2='A' href="#">UK Tote</a></li>

    $('#target').val($(this).attr('rel'));
    $('#target2').val($(this).attr('rel2'));

Answer (score 1):

you can get both the values in a single hidden field by using comma or any other separator as follows

$('#target').val($(this).attr('rel')+","+$(this).attr('rel2'));